# iOS navigation with tab bar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have an app that has a standard UITabBar in the bottom of the view. This tab bar remains in the same place the entire life time of the app.

My question is, is there a standard way to handle sub navigation in a nice way using a storyboard? I would like one of the "tab bar item views" to be tabable into three new views without disturbing the main tab bar.

In the current app, there is a Segmented UI Control at the top of the view that switches view programatically into a child view.

Johan

Comment: You have to render your views in the ViewController which has UITabBar

Comment: The main viewcontroller already has one UITabBar with "global tabs" that live the entire lifespan. I was aiming for a sub navigation, keeping the global tabs and adding some other means of sub navigation.

Comment: So you want to open a new view when clicking on tab bar item?

Comment: I have one viewcontroller/view for each of the tabs. Works good. When clicking the first tab I would like some kind of sub navigation to, let's say three other views. Since the tabbar is already occupied, what would be the ios way of doing this? In the current app, there is a segmented ui control at the top of the view that switches between three subviews. This does not play well with storyboarding.

Comment: So just replace the view of of your viewController to view you want to change.

Comment: The main question being, how do you do that with a storyboard. I'm aiming to get as much UI design as possible without coding. Mostly for academic reasons. If this isn't possible, do I have to create xib-files along side my storyboard for the stand-alone views?